# Is the notification of completion of a background job based on some callback event-handling?

Tags: bash, background-process

When a background job in bash completes, it will notify the terminal.

```
$ sleep 3 &
[1] 17527
$ 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 3
```

- Is the notification based on some callback  event-handling?
- does the background job notify the terminal  when it completes, by sending some signal to the terminal?
- Why do I have to hit a return (i.e. run an empty command) to see the notification on the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#JOB_CONTROL):

> The  shell  learns  immediately  whenever  a job changes state.  Normally, `bash` waits until it is about to
>          print a prompt before reporting changes in a job's status so as to not interrupt any other output.  If the
>          `-b`  option  to  the  `set`  builtin  command is enabled, `bash` reports such changes immediately.  Any trap on
>          `SIGCHLD` is executed for each child that exits.

This explains why you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before seeing the notification. You can change that by running `set -b`. It doesn’t have much to do with the *terminal*, job control is managed by the shell. When a background process terminates, the parent receives a [`SIGCHLD` signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html); that’s the notification.

Comment: Thanks. "When a background process terminates, the parent receives a SIGCHLD signal;" Is the parent the bash process or the terminal process? Is outputting "Done" to stdout the bash's handler when receiving signal `SIGCHLD`?

Comment: The parent is the shell. “Done” is output either by the shell’s signal handler, if notifications are asynchronous (`set -b`), or before printing the prompt.

Comment: Thanks. Does `set +b` set up the default behavior?

Comment: I was wondering how to solve this problem https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460135/how-can-i-periodically-record-the-dir-stack-and-jobs-of-a-shell-without-occupyin#comment836916_460167 adding `set -b` to the script doesn't seem to work