# How can I periodically record the dir stack and jobs of a shell without occupying the shell?

Tags: bash, background-process, jobs

I have a script

```
$ cat my.sh 
#! /bin/bash -
dirs -l > /tmp/test/dirs_record
jobs > /tmp/test/jobs_record
```

So when I `source ./my.sh`, it will output the dir stack and jobs in the invoking shell.

I have another script `schedule.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash -
while : ; do eval "${@}" ; sleep 10 ; done
```

Running `source schedule.sh source ./my.sh` in a bash shell can [periodically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458672/can-i-schedule-running-a-script-inside-a-particular-shell-process-once-in-a-whil) record the dir stack and jobs in the invoking bash shell.

But I  want to run other commands in the same shell, and want `source schedule.sh source ./my.sh` to  record the up-to-date dir stack and jobs periodically, so I put it in background `source schedule.sh source ./my.sh &`, and then since `jobs` and `dirs` are running in a subshell instead of the invoking shell, any change to the jobs or dir stack to the invoking shell will not be recorded. See  [Why do `jobs` and `dirs` run in command subsitution, process substitution, pipeline, and background jobs output the same as in original shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458984/why-do-jobs-and-dirs-run-in-command-subsitution-process-substitution-pipel)

How can I periodically record the dir stack and jobs of a shell without occupying the shell? For example, can I run a background job directly in the invoking shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a signal trap, and running sleep && kill in the background:

```
$ cat monitor.sh
# monitor stuff in the background

# ensure this file is sourced, not executed: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/109 
sourced() { [[ ${FUNCNAME[1]} == "source" ]]; }
sourced || { echo "source me"; exit 1; }
unset -f sourced

__MY_PID=$$

trap __usr1_trap USR1

__usr1_trap() {
    dirs -l >| /tmp/test/dirs_record
    jobs    >| /tmp/test/jobs_record
    __schedule_trap &
}

__schedule_trap() {
    sleep 60
    kill -USR1 $__MY_PID
}

# trigger the signal handler, which will reschedule itself
kill -USR1 $__MY_PID
```

Launch it with `. /path/to/monitor.sh`

Note that I use `>|` as the redirection operator in the signal handler because I run with `set -o noclobber` to avoid accidentally overwriting files: here we want to overwrite the files on purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Is prefix `__`  naming convention to distinguish names created by you from those implicitly by the shell?

Comment: Yeah. I picked it up from some coding convention that "private methods" start with an underscore. I'd be unlikely to type it by accident.

Comment: How would you stop it from running? `trap "" USR1`?

Comment: One strange problem when I run your script is that the signal stops being sent and trapped whenever the shell is idle i.e. without my running any command,  Is it because `__schedule_trap &`  need me to type RETURN key to finish sending the signal?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398860/is-the-notification-of-completion-of-a-background-job-based-on-some-callback-eve